# Evaluating $P(X_{3}=j,X_{1}=i|X_{2}=k)$ on markov chain trouble

Tags: probability, markov-process

I just would like to evaluate $P(X_{3}=j,X_{1}=i|X_{2}=k)$

So I tried:

$P(X_{3}=j,X_{1}=i|X_{2}=k)
=P(X_{3}=j|X_{2}=k)P(X_{1}=i|X_{2}=k)$

The trouble is evaluating $P(X_{1}=i|X_{2}=k)$

I tried $P(X_{1}=i|X_{2}=k)=P(X_{1}=i)$ since I think the past doesnt depend from future and I applied total probability theorem so:

$P(X_1=i)=\sum_{l \in S}P(X_1=i|X_0=l)$ where $S$ is the state space.

But I'm not sure if this independence holds if not what should I do?

PS: Assume transition matrix is known so $\sum_{l \in S}P(X_1=i|X_0=l)$ is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened in the future variables clues what had happened in the past, so the assumption $p(x_1|x_2)=p(x_1)$ is not correct. You should use Bayes theorem to calculate it:
$$p(x_1|x_2)=\frac{p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1)}{p(x_2)}$$

You can calculate $p(x_i)$ from total probability theorem, or alternatively do the same calculations using some matrix multiplications as described in [this notes](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Efewster/325/notes/ch8.pdf), page 10.

Comment: I voted up and go it as the answer as bayes theorem will solve the problem regardless indepence holds or not but It doesnt make sense, ok!, a finite markov chain will reset but index time not so $X_2$ is the first second transition ever, I`m looking over if the results will be the same.

Comment: I looked over and the results are not the same, how weird.

Comment: @DaviAmérico I apologize for the typo, I corrected it. But, I couldn't follow your objection in your first message. Can you clarify a bit more about what feels wrong?

Comment: I misread `What happened in the future variables clues what had happened in the past`, eng is not my main language, now past depending from future makes a little bit sense but thats another discussion thank you.

Comment: There is no way to get through this by total probability I was using the wrong theorem, in right way we would have $P(x_1)=\sum_{i \in S}P(x_1|x_0=i)P(x_0=i)$ how would I get $P(X_0=i)$?

Comment: That is the initial condition you assume or are given, e.g. if equally likely states, and the number of states is $n$, then it's $1/n$. If not, it should be given explicitly.

Comment: I have the transition matrix for this problem would it help? since the matrix just keeps the conditional probabilities

Comment: No, transition matrix does not say anything about the initial conditions.

Comment: I think that my professor formulated this question wrong, it seems impossible to get this probability without any initial conditions.

Comment: The given chain is recurrent, aperiodic and irreductible does it help in anything? Sorry I didnt expect this.

Comment: Those props. are deduced from transition matrix.

Comment: I've deduced it